# Use LLVM debugger inside Emacs on OSX Yosemite

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I want to know if is possible to use the LLVM debugger with the Emacs, something like the *M-x gdb* interface standard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding LLVM debugger support to Emacs is surprisingly (or not, depending on your level of cynicism) contentious.

In February, 2015, [Richard Stallman wrote](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-02/msg00360.html):

> > The LLVM source repository includes a patch adding basic lldb support to gud.el.
>
> It looks like there is a systematic effort to attack GNU packages.
> The GNU Project needs to respond strategically, which means not by
> having each GNU package cooperate with each attack.  For now, please
> do NOT install this change.

Stefan Monnier, one of the current maintainers, is [much less hostile to the change](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-02/msg00287.html):

> Thanks, Andrew.  I'd be happy to incorporate such a patch.
> I took a quick look at the code, and seen from afar, there's no problem
> with it, so all that is really needed is to clear the copyright status
> of this code.

As of March, 2015, I don't believe that the LLVM debugger patch has been accepted.